# How can I change an ASP.NET Gridview's cssClass with Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

I would like to access the asp.net gridview's cssClass attribute and change it with Javascript.

I know I can access other individual style attributes like so:

```
document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').style
```

But I'd like to change the cssClass in particular.  This is what I have after attempting the first suggestion.  It does not work as of yet.  I placed that line you gave me in the first part of a function that highlights a selected row so that all previously highlighted rows would revert back to the normal style. Thoughts?

```
function ChangeRowColor(rowID) {
    document.getElementById('<%=gvxTaskList.ClientID%>').className += "tablestyle";

    var color = document.getElementById(rowID).style.backgroundColor;
    if (color != 'yellow')
        oldColor = color;
    if (color == 'yellow')
        document.getElementById(rowID).style.backgroundColor = oldColor;
    else document.getElementById(rowID).style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
}
```

Comment: Apologies!  I probably need to change the altrowstyle and rowstyle.  So how would I accomplish that?

Comment: `.className += "tablestyle"` will only work the first time and calling that function again it would turn the css off. Why? `class="tablestyletablestyle"`. TableStyle twice becomes a name of another class. I'll update my answer to cater for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').className = "class";
```

And to add to existing class

```
document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').className += " class";
```

### Update

```
function addClass()
{
    var exClass = document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').className;

    if(exClass.indexOf('className') == -1)  //check that the class does not already exist
    {
        if(exClass.length == 0)
           document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').className += 'className'; //add
        else
           document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').className += ' className'; //append
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

cssClass in asp.net will simply translate to classes in client-side html, so for example, code like this in .net side:

```
<asp:datagrid id="myGrid" cssClass="myClass" runat=server></asp:datagrid">
```

will translate - roughly - into:

```
<table id="someRandomIdOrClientIdThatYouSet" class="myClass"><tr>....</tr></table>
```

so to achieve what you want, in javascript, you can change it with:

```
document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').className = "newClassName";
```

or with a library like jQuery:

```
$('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').addClass("newClassName")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  document.getElementById('<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').className += "class";
```

Comment: I placed that line you gave me in the first part of a function that highlights a selected row so that all previously highlighted rows would revert back to the normal style; however, that didn't work.  I posted the code above as this space is limited